# Yolov8 Backbone, How can i learn which backbone algorithm used my yolo model?

Tags: python, yolov8

How can i learn which backbone algorithm used my yolo model ?

could not find how to check it actually? is there any way to check it?

How can i learn which backbone algorithm used my yolo model ?
could not find how to check it actually? is there any way to check it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.